# Laravel 5 how to specify a standard blade file within a Route::get

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on a `Laravel` project implementing `React` for the front end.

I've set up a couple of routes and have created two blade files for both the dashboard and a clients list page.

However, after consideration I feel that maybe a single blade file with a header and footer and just a `#content` div in the middle would be more efficient.

I cannot see how to specific which blade file for the route. At first, I thought I was specifying it using the `name()` function on the Route but I am wrong. Here are my routes in my `web.php` file:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/clients', 'ClientController@index')->name('clients');
```

And I created two blade files:

```
home.blade.php
clients.blade.php
```

Which basically contain:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div id="content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Except in the clients template I have the title 'Clients' not 'Dashboard'.

This is the `app.blade.php` which each template extends:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Reserve Shark') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Reserve Shark') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I changed the client route's name to 'home' (thinking it would use the home blade file) it didn't change. So, for the purpose of testing, I changed it to 'blah' which didn't change anything. I even changed the route itself to client-page and the same in my `app.js` file:

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Example} />
        <Route path="/client-page" component={Client} />
    </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Yet there is no change.

When I changed my clients.blade.php file to `clients2.blade.php` I got an error stating that `clients.blade.php` didn't exist.

So my question is: where on earth is Laravel stipulating that this page uses **THAT** blade file?

Is it possible to somehow change it so every route uses the same file and the only difference is the data that's injected into the `#content` div?

Comment: In your controller (e.g. ClientController), within the index method, there should either be a `view(...)` helper method or a `View::make(...)` static method. Does this have the route names you are seeing?

Comment: Ah, you're correct - looks like the template I used had these `index()` functions already set up with standard view references! Thank you, makes sense now. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done! Glad we found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller (e.g. ClientController), within the `index` method, there should either be a `view(...)` helper method or a `View::make(...)` static method.

Change the value to change the blade template used.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `->name('home')` attach to your route, you just specifie the name of the route by default Laravel will name your route as `home.route`, and this is just to help you remember the name of your route when you whan to return same URL instead of writing the URL manualy you can use the `route()` helper

To specifie the blade template which you want to render you must put in you index method of you `HomeController`

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        /* here goes all other code */ 
        return View::make('home'); // Laravel will render your home.blade.php file
    }
}

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /* here goes all other code */ 
        return View::make('clients'); // Laravel will render your clients.blade.php file
    }
}
```

don't forget to use the `Illuminate\Supports\Facades\View`